# PHP remove string from a string between two commas where the string starts with specific item

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to remove a string between two commas within a larger string that starts with a specifica item.

So this is the larger string:-

```
#navMain ul li a,.navBreadCrumb1 .nav1 ul li,.top-specials
```

I have a query that selects .navBreadCrumb1 and I want to be able to remove everything from .navBreadCrumb1 to next comma so the string above would become:-

```
#navMain ul li a,.top-specials
```

The query could select multiple items (i.e it could have selected #navMain - in which case i would need it to remove #navMain ul li a,)

I am pretty usless with preg_replace() and I guess that what I would have to use that to achive this but honestly do not have a clue.

Can any one help?

Comment: Can you show what you have already in place so we can take it from there?

Comment: Time to brush up [PHP Pattern Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). If a `.` needs to be escaped and `[^,]*` matches 0+ chars other than `,`, what pattern can you come up with (do not forget about regex delimiters, i.e. `/` and `/` around your pattern)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, here is one example if you're trying to just get rid of a section of text between two commas:

```
$string = '#navMain ul li a,.navBreadCrumb1 .nav1 ul li,.top-specials';
$stringArray = explode(',', $string);
$stringNew = $stringArray[0].','.$stringArray[2];
echo $stringNew;
```

Returns `#navMain ul li a,.top-specials`

The only problem with this example are the assumptions which must be made:

- an array of the string will return 3 items
- it really is just a string and not markup
- it really is just as easy as concatenating the parts you want after you explode the string

Now, using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you could get yet another array using a regex pattern:

```
(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*)
```

The first group matches up to the first comma, the second up to the next comma and then the rest of the string. You could code it up like this, using `$string` from above:

```
$pattern = '/(.*?,)(.*?,)(.*)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` would contain this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #navMain ul li a,.navBreadCrumb1 .nav1 ul li,.top-specials
    [1] => #navMain ul li a,
    [2] => .navBreadCrumb1 .nav1 ul li,
    [3] => .top-specials
)
```

To get the result you're looking for you would end up concatenating `$matches[1] . ',' . $matches[3]`

The *are* other regex patterns you could experiment with and use, for example you using [regex lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
$lookaround = '/(?=,)(.*?)(?=,)/';
$newString = preg_replace($lookaround, '', $string);
```

The pattern matches the text below because of its relationship to the first and second comma in the string:

```
,.navBreadCrumb1 .nav1 ul li
```

Now `$newString` (the result of the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)) we create contains exactly what you're looking for even if the regex is not particularly efficient if you're examining a lot of strings. There is no concatenation and the pattern is much less fragile than the examples I provided previously. We essentially replace the section from the first comma to the next comma with nothing, leaving the string you're looking for.